# Age() function not working with time.Time

Tags: postgresql, go, time

Trying to use age() function from postgresql with DateOfBirth

```
type Person struct {
  ID int
  DOB time.Time
}
```

```
query := `SELECT id, AGE(dateofbirth) from person WHERE id = $1`
```

But got an error

> Unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *time.Time

The age() function work if I just pass the DOB as string

```
type Person struct {
  ID int
  DOB string
}
```

But I want to check the validity of DOB so I use time.Parse("2006-01-02", DOB)

```
func createPerson(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  err := r.ParseForm()
  if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
  }
  dob := r.PostForm.Get("dob")
  birthday, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", dob)

  err = models.person.Insert(birthday)
  if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Server Error: ", err)
        return
  }
  http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
}

func getPerson(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  id, err := strconv.Atoi(chi.URLParam(r, "id"))
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Not found", err)
    return
  }
  person, err = models.person.Get(id)
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal("Server Error: ", err)
      return
  }
  render.HTML(w, http.StatusOK, "person.html", person)
}
```

Comment: Looks like that's a Go error. Please show your Go code.

Comment: I just process the form input which is type="date" with `dob := r.PostForm.Get("dob")` and validate then parse `birthday, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", dob)` and `models.person.Insert(birthday)`
Then, `person, err := models.person.Get(id)`

Comment: Include the Go code directly in your question, and also show **exactly where** the error is occurring.

Comment: Added code in question. I don't think there is wrong with the code because age() function work if DOB is string

Comment: "**Unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *time.Time**" Please show exactly where this error came from in your code. An error message is much less useful when you don't know which function produced it. This is essential to help people help you.

Comment: The error happen in the getPerson() which at the line `log.Fatal("Server Error: ", err)`. It says sql scan error on column index 3, name "age": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *time.Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database driver is responsible for transforming the incoming data from the database into Go data types. I'll assume you're using `pq`, which has the following [rules about data types](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Data_Types):

> This package returns the following types for values from the PostgreSQL backend:
>
> - integer types smallint, integer, and bigint are returned as int64
> - floating-point types real and double precision are returned as float64
> - character types char, varchar, and text are returned as string
> - temporal types date, time, timetz, timestamp, and timestamptz are returned as time.Time
> - the boolean type is returned as bool
> - the bytea type is returned as []byte
>
> All other types are returned directly from the backend as []byte values in text format.

In [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html), the `AGE` function returns data type `interval`. This is not one of the directly supported data types, so `pq` processes it as `[]byte`. That is why it works when you make `DOB` a `string`. Conversion between `[]byte` and `string` in Go is trivial, so the driver is able to fill in the value.

The driver fails to fill the `[]byte` into a `time.Time` value because it doesn't know what conversion routine to use. Actually, there is no direct conversion routine because `interval` represents a duration of time, while `time.Time` represents an instance of time. `interval` is more analogous to a `time.Duration` value. Still, the driver doesn't support any automatic conversion from `interval` to any type, and I'm not aware of a way to add a new conversion. You would have to implement the conversion yourself after fetching the data from the database.

You could also switch to the [`pgx` driver](https://github.com/jackc/pgx), which supports an [`Interval`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5@v5.1.1/pgtype#Interval) type.